# How can I see all items checked out by other users in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I want a list of all the checked out files, by all users, in a project in TFS 2005.
All I can see now are *my* checked out files - in the pending changes window. I remember that in Source Safe there was such an option - is there one in TFS 2005?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [October 2008 edition of the TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx) includes "Team Members" functionality that allows you to do this, and more.

There is more information on this feature on [Brian Harry's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2008/10/01/preview-of-the-next-tfs-power-tools-release.aspx).

Comment: The poster appears to be using TFS 2005

Comment: Ah! Well, surely it's time they upgraded?! :-)

Comment: We upgraded Team Explorer to 2008! (And stayed with team server 2005)

Answer (score 21):

I use:

```
tf status itemspec /user:* /recursive
```

in the VS Command Prompt. itemspec is the TFS path to the item you want to search for checkouts. No extra installations needed ;)

Comment: BTW, if there's a lot of checkouts, it can be useful to output it to a text file. `tf status itemspec /user:* /recursive > C:\Checkouts.txt`

Comment: I ended up starting with this command and my final command looks like this below. My goal was to create a uniform output that I could then consume programmatically. `tf status /user:* /recursive /format:detailed >C:\CheckoutsDetailed.txt`

Comment: `tf status itemspec /user:* /recursive` -> **Changes from local workspaces will not be displayed when using the /user option if a workspace is not supplied or if that workspace is on another machine.
There are no pending changes.** I needed to add **./** `tf status ./ itemspec /user:* /recursive` -> **15498 change(s)**

Comment: `tf status /user:* /recursive`

Comment: I also had to include the collection: `tf status /user:* /recursive /collection:https://tfs.MyServer.com/MyCollection`

Answer (score 13):

I usually use [TFS SideKicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Power Tools option: *"Open Visual Studio > Click File > Source Control > Find In Source Control > Status
Select "Display all checked out" or "Display files checked out to" (to filter changes by user)
Hit Find"*

http://geekswithblogs.net/MikeParks/archive/2009/09/16/tfs---view-all-pending-changes-for-all-users.aspx

__

Another way using .net (complete [source](https://github.com/ImaginaryDevelopment/config/blob/master/My%20Documents/LINQPad%20Queries/Tfs/ViaTfsDlls/QueryAllPendingChanges.linq))

```
using(var tfsPc=new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri))

    {
        var vcs=tfsPc.GetService<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer>();

        var srcRoot=vcs.GetItem(srcpath);


        var pendings=vcs.QueryPendingSets(new[]{srcRoot.ServerItem}, RecursionType.Full,null,null).AsEnumerable();
        if(onlyLocks)
            pendings=pendings.Where(pq=>pq.PendingChanges.Any(pc=>pc.IsLock));
        if(minDate.HasValue)
            pendings=pendings.Where(pq => pq.PendingChanges.Any( pc => pc.CreationDate > minDate.Value));
        var pendingQuery=pendings
            .OrderByDescending(p=>p.PendingChanges.Max(d=>d.CreationDate));
        pendingQuery.Dump("pending");   


    }
```

[similar to above, but join the ActiveDirectory to get a user's name](https://github.com/ImaginaryDevelopment/config/blob/master/My%20Documents/LINQPad%20Queries/Tfs/ViaTfsDlls/queryTfs10Api.linq)