# Show list of checked out items (both locking types) TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs, locking, azure-devops

We are using Team Foundation Server for a team project. Everyone has Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. (some updated to Update 4). For hosting we use VSO (visual studio Online, microsoft service to host a free tfs project).

Now there are 2 lock types that TFS supports:

**1. Unchanged - Keep any existing lock.**

**2. Check In - Allow other users to check out but prevent them from checking in.**

So lock type 1 allows us to work on the same class and check-in edits togheter, while lock type 2 allows us to lock a file, make edits without anyone else can interfere the edits. Someone else cannot get the same lock type as well. (kind of rules out some Merging problems).

**The Question:**

How can I see a list of checked out items, from BOTH lock types, lock type 1 and/or lock type 2. Lock type 2 is already shown in Source Control. Lock type 1 is not.

*TFS Powertools and TF Sidekicks*

Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477314/how-can-i-see-all-items-checked-out-by-other-users-in-tfs) suggests, I should use TFS Power Tools. This does enable one to show a list of **Locked** (lock type 2) items, but not checked out files with lock type 1.

**Edit:** Same goes for Team Foundation Sidekicks, only showing lock type 2
Also, there happens to be TFS 2013 power tools and VS 2013 power tools, installed both, but no luck (vs2013 power tools is a good suggestion btw)

**Why?**
If you would like to know why this would be nice to have.
TFS works great for Workflow management, you can assign tasks to members which integrates within visual studio, VS CodeLens (after Update 4, when using VSO) allows you to see the changes within the code. So we have a general rule that you put a Task from *To-Do* into *In Progress* to keep an overview what everyone is working on. Sometimes however, you can't complete a task in one day, the task remains in progress, but you don't know if he actually is working on it or not.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve a cultural issue with technology. The easiest way to know if someone is working on a task or if they're blocked is to **talk to them about it**. This is why teams frequently have short, daily stand-up meetings.

Comment: true, but not everyone is in the office all the time when we are working on a project, so, thats the reason why it should be nice to have...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)  from Attrice

Comment: Download and tested it, same thing. Only showing lock type 2, like I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using local workspaces then you will never get a server side list of checked out files.

You are best going and asking the developer about that task. Out letting the development team figure it out for themselves at the daily scrum.

Comment: Well, I guess you are right, but my question is.. WHY? They can show me lock type 2 in source control, why not lock type 1? It's not that big of a deal in my opinion... Same protocol I would say.. Thanks for that statement though

Comment: Because lock type 1 no longer talks to the server with local workspaces.

Comment: Thanks for your response, think this is a nice suggestion for microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekick is one of the option which is far better.

Another option is via TFS powertools. See link

[How to undo another user's checkout in TFS via the GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690351/how-to-undo-another-users-checkout-in-tfs-via-the-gui)

Comment: Download and tested it, same thing. Only showing lock type 2, like I mentioned in my question. And.. Please read the full question before answering, because I already mentioned TFS powertools..

Answer (score 0):

In the Source Control window you can right-click on a folder then choose Find, Find by status.
It should display Lock type 1 also.